# Imprimir una funcion en un textarea a traves de un boton onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, textarea

soy muy principiante en la programacion y estoy empezando a "resolver" problemas cotidianos, el codigo es una calculadora sencilla con varios productos.

Busco que al hacer uso del atributo `onclick` en el boton "calcular" se muestre el resultado de la variable "calculoProductos" en el TextArea de html pero no logro hacer que funcione, previamente mostraba el resultado correcto mediante un `alert`, pero me gustaria que se reflejara en el TextArea.

Adjunto los codigos para su analisis en busca de errores.

**- Codigo HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora de Pan </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estiloPanes.CSS">
    <script src="codigoPanes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="myForm">
            <label for="panes" class="labelProductos">Panes </label>
            <br>
            <input type="number" id="panes" class="listaProductos">
            <br>

            <label for="pizzas" class="labelProductos">Pizzas </label>
            <input type="number" id="pizzas" class="listaProductos">
            <br>

            <label for="coca" class="labelProductos">Coca/Fresca </label>
            <input type="number" id="coca" class="listaProductos">
            <br>

            <label for="refresco" class="labelProductos">Refresco </label>
            <input type="number" id="refresco" class="listaProductos">
            <br>

            <label for="empanadas" class="labelProductos">Empanadas </label>
            <input type="number" id="empanadas" class="listaProductos">
            <br>
            <br>
    
            <input type="button" class="botonesProductos" value="Calcular" onclick ="granTotal()">
            <br>
            <br>
            <textarea class="salidaCalculo" cols="52" rows="5"></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="button" class="botonesProductos" value="Borrar" onclick ="borrarContenido()">
        </form>
            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**- Codigo JS**

```
function granTotal() {
    let panes = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);
    let pizzas = parseInt(document.getElementById("pizzas").value);
    let coca = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);
    let refresco = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);
    let empanadas = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);

    let calculoProductos = ((panes * 7) + (pizzas * 22) + (coca * 11) + (refresco * 13) + (empanadas *15));

    //alert("el total es " + calculoProductos);
    document.getElementById("salidaCalculo") = salidaCalculo;
}


function borrarContenido(){
    document.getElementById("panes").value = "";
    document.getElementById("pizzas").value = "";
    document.getElementById("coca").value = "";
    document.getElementById("refresco").value = "";
    document.getElementById("empanadas").value = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu primer error está aquí:

```
let coca = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);
let refresco = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);
let empanadas = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value);
```

Estás utilizando incorrectamente los id para obtener los valores de los elementos, deberías obtener los campos correctos, así:

```
let coca = parseInt(document.getElementById("coca").value);
let refresco = parseInt(document.getElementById("refresco").value);
let empanadas = parseInt(document.getElementById("empanadas").value);
```

Otro error es que estás asignando de manera incorrecta a tu `texarea`:

```
document.getElementById("salidaCalculo") = salidaCalculo;
```

La etiqueta `texarea` tiene **solo una clase** llamada `salidaCalculo`, y podemos capturar esa clase con `querySelector()` y asignarle el valor del total:

```
document.querySelector(".salidaCalculo").value = "El total es: " + calculoProductos;
```

#### Demo:

```js
function granTotal() {
  let panes = parseInt(document.getElementById("panes").value || 0);
  let pizzas = parseInt(document.getElementById("pizzas").value || 0);
  let coca = parseInt(document.getElementById("coca").value || 0);
  let refresco = parseInt(document.getElementById("refresco").value || 0);
  let empanadas = parseInt(document.getElementById("empanadas").value || 0);

  let calculoProductos = ((panes * 7) + (pizzas * 22) + (coca * 11) + (refresco * 13) + (empanadas *15));

  alert("el total es: " + calculoProductos);
  // document.getElementById("salidaCalculo") = salidaCalculo;
  document.querySelector(".salidaCalculo").value = "El total es: " + calculoProductos;
}

function borrarContenido(){
  document.getElementById("panes").value = "";
  document.getElementById("pizzas").value = "";
  document.getElementById("coca").value = "";
  document.getElementById("refresco").value = "";
  document.getElementById("empanadas").value = "";
  document.querySelector(".salidaCalculo").value = ""; // también limpiamos al texarea.
  document.getElementById("panes").focus(); // y hacemos focus al primer input.
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora de Pan </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estiloPanes.CSS">
    <script src="codigoPanes.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form id="myForm">
        <label for="panes" class="labelProductos">Panes </label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="panes" class="listaProductos">
        <br>
        <label for="pizzas" class="labelProductos">Pizzas </label>
        <input type="number" id="pizzas" class="listaProductos">
        <br>
        <label for="coca" class="labelProductos">Coca/Fresca </label>
        <input type="number" id="coca" class="listaProductos">
        <br>
        <label for="refresco" class="labelProductos">Refresco </label>
        <input type="number" id="refresco" class="listaProductos">
        <br>
        <label for="empanadas" class="labelProductos">Empanadas </label>
        <input type="number" id="empanadas" class="listaProductos">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="botonesProductos" value="Calcular" onclick ="granTotal()">
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="salidaCalculo" cols="52" rows="5"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="botonesProductos" value="Borrar" onclick ="borrarContenido()">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está genial la solución! Solo le agregaría un pequeño "control" cuando el valor de algún `input` esté vacío ya que da como resultado `NaN`.

Comment: @DjCrazy buena observación, ahora si ya quedó je

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me habia dado cuenta de esos errores y mucho menos de la asignacion incorrecta en el textarea, el codigo funciona perfectamente, te lo agradezco mucho!

Comment: @JoseJavierPerezHernandez me alegro, recuerda verificar la respuesta marcándole al ✔️ (que se encuentra al lado izquierdo de mi respuesta) si te sirvió para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos y éxitos!